# Django raw query - how to pass postgres array value as parameter?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm working with raw SQL queries in a Django+PostgreSQL app, and I've come across the problem of having to pass as parameter a PostgreSQL Array value (of type `tags = ArrayField(m.CharField(max_length=80)` in app / `tags character varying(80)[]` in db).

I'm using code like this:

```
Product.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_code_products WHERE tags @> %s', [
    ['red'] # also tried with simply string '{"red"}' but that didn't work either, also tried with tuple
])
```

...in the hope of getting SQL like this generated:

```
SELECT * FROM myapp_code_products WHERE (tags @> '{"red"}')
```

but I either get simply nothing substituted like `(tags @>)` or list or tuple substitution like `(tags @> ['red'])` or `(tags @> ('red'))` and obviously none of this result in a valid contains query.

And, if anyone is wondering, the substituted parameter is user-supplied, so **just completely bypassing parameter substitution here is not an option security-wise.**

**Note:** also, using raw queries is to be considered a requirement here, using querysets and model queries is not an option here.

(Detail: I'm using Django 1.10.5 with Python 3.6.0 and PostgreSQL 9.3 on Windows  10 64bit)

Comment: So, you don't want to use `ArrayField`'s [contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contains) lookup which builds `@>` queries for you, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that works for me on postgres **9.6**:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> a = ["a","b","c"]
>>> b = ["b"]
>>> c = connection.cursor()
>>> c.execute("""SELECT %s::VARCHAR[] @> %s::VARCHAR[];""", (a,b))
>>> c.fetchall()
[(True,)]
```

Keep in mind that if `tags` is an `ArrayField`, this should work as well:

```
Product.objects.filter(tags__contains=['red'])
```

Comment: thanks! this worked. what I tried before was `array%s::varchar[]` without realizing that `array` is added automatically when substituting a list as param value, so it ended up producing `arrayARRAY[...]::varchar[]`. I was just not paying attention

Comment: and if you could please edit you answer to also include a `>>> c = connection.cursor()` line to be 100% executable code :)